# Mark brand keywords in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently conducting a keyword analysis using Python. I have a DataFrame `df` which looks like this:

```
keyword        url
camera         canon.com
canon camera   canon.com
```

In SEO you distinguish between brand and generic keywords. Now, the first one is generic, while the second contains the brand name mentioned in the URL. Based on that, I would like to establish a new column `df['match']` and fill it based on the following condition:

```
brands = ['canon', 'canon.de']  

if df['keyword'] in brands == True
       df['match'] = 'brand'
    else
       df['match'] = 'generic'
```

I know that the syntax is completely wrong, but I hope you get what I'm trying to achieve:

```
keyword        url          match
camera         canon.com    generic
canon camera   canon.com    brand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is test in splited `keyword`s in list comprehension and `any` and then set new column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = [any(x in y for x in x.split()) for x, y in df[['keyword', 'url']].values]
df['match'] = np.where(mask, 'brand', 'generic')
print (df)
        keyword        url    match
0        camera  canon.com  generic
1  canon camera  canon.com    brand
```

EDIT: It values are in list is possible use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with joined values `|` for regex `or`:

```
mask = df['keyword'].str.contains('|'.join(brands))
df['match'] = np.where(mask, 'brand', 'generic')
print (df)
        keyword        url    match
0        camera  canon.com  generic
1  canon camera  canon.com    brand
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It indeed works as I wanted. However, I realized after a run on real data that I might need to supply a dedicated list of brand names to enhance the results. How would this look like if I would have supplied a static list instead of dynamically pulling the value from `df['url']`?

Comment: sure, I edited to match the new "requirement" of matching against a distinct list.